# how to check for empty pointers

Tags: objective-c, c

say I have a struct,

```
struct room{
char name[21];
int num1;
int num2;
struct room *doors[4];

};
```

so number of rooms are given ,

```
struct room rm[Number_of_room];
```

and each room:

```
scanf(name | num1 | num2)
strcpy(rm[i].name, name)
rm[i].num1 = num1
rm[i].num2 = num2
```

all that works fine.

Until, I wish to check rather the door is pointed at something already or not,

```
UP=0, RIGHT=1, DOWN=2, LEFT=3

rm[i].doors[0] = &rm[j]   // this is how I point the door to an other room, works fine too.
```

but when I check for strlen or null, suppose I only assign one door from room1 to room2, room1 somehow has more than one non-empty doors.

Is there a way to check rather the doors are empty or not?

Thanks

Comment: What was your reason for using a `struct` for this instead of an `Object`?

Comment: its the assignment requirement, header file is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize a new object of the `struct room` type, set its `doors` members to NULL. Afterwards compare to NULL and find if they're already set

```
struct room object;
object.doors[0] = NULL;
object.doors[1] = NULL;
object.doors[2] = NULL;
object.doors[3] = NULL;

if (object.doors[2] != NULL) {
    /* already assigned something */
    /* maybe reset? */
    object.doors[2] = NULL;
};
```